# How can I list version name in my silverlight application?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-silverlight-api, versioning

I need to populate combobox with arcsde version name in my silverlight 5 application.
Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: What have to done till now?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

1. Use GP service to list versions - there is a step-by-step tutorial [here (for 10.1)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Listing_creating_and_deleting_GDB_versions/0154000005vz000000/). Get the output list and show it in your app.
2. Access the DBMS [sde_versions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Geodatabase_system_tables/002q00000080000000/) table with SQL and get the list of versions in your app.
3. I am not sure if API itself has some methods of listing SDE versions, I am a bit unsure.

Comment: hello can you please tell what is the difference between getting versionlist form GP Service and accessing DBMS as you suggested.  I tried both options and I am getting the list also.But the confusion is that why to use GP service if I can directly access DBMS.